# List within a Tree?

Tags: c, list, linked-list, tree, binary-tree

A small query really with reference to Structs.

If I had a

```
Struct Node { 
  char *number; 
  struct Node *next; 
 }List;
```

and a tree Structure:

```
struct Node {
  char *name;
  char *number;
  struct Node *right;
  struct Node *left;
};
```

and I wanted to design it, such that each Node within my Tree, can each contain a LIST of Phone Numbers, is there a way in which I can do this, and if so, how exactly can I reference my struct List within my Tree?

EDIT:

Any ideas as to why this is seg faulting? Using the Structs recommended below.

```
TreeNode* AddNode(TreeNode *root, ListNode *list, char *name, char *phonenum) {
int comparison;
if ( root == NULL ) {
    root = (TreeNode *)malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
    list = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    root->name = strdup(name); root->list->number = strdup(phonenum);
    root->left = root->right = NULL;
```

Comment: Small question. If I was to then add something to the list contained within the tree, i.e. a Number, would I access like following: (Imagine root is my tree node). root->list->number = strdup(number) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd simply do it like so:

```
typedef struct Node {
  char* name;
  List* list;
  struct Node *right;
  struct Node *left;
} Node;
```

Then in order to get a local copy of the first element of the list in each node, you'd do something like the following:

```
Node* treenode; //this is pointing to some node in the tree

char* num_buffer = strdup(treenode->list->number);
//use num_buffer and then call free() on it when you're finished
```

If you wanted to get a number that was not the first number in the list, you would have to create a search function for your linked list.

Comment: Would that in theory mean, I dont need the char *number defined within my Tree Node? All would just go straight to my list ?

Comment: Small question. If I was to then add something to the list contained within the tree, i.e. a Number, would I access like following: (Imagine root is my tree node).  root->list->number = strdup(number) ?

Comment: Yes ... and if it was a number that was further down the list (i.e., it was not the first number in the list like right now), you would need to iterate down the list first before doing the assignment

Answer (score 1):

Can you do something like this?

```
typedef struct ListNode
{
    char            *number;
    struct ListNode *next;
} ListNode;

typedef struct TreeNode
{
    char            *name;
    ListNode        *numbers;
    struct TreeNode *left;
    struct TreeNode *right;
} TreeNode;
```

Comment: Would that in theory mean, I dont need the char *number defined within my Tree Node? All would just go straight to my list ?

Comment: @user1048116: It's up to you.  Why would you need both the single `char *number` **and** a linked-list of numbers?

Comment: Sorry, I just realised, thats me being a total fool. Cheers!

Comment: Small question. If I was to then add something to the list contained within the tree, i.e. a Number, would I access like following: (Imagine root is my tree node). root->list->number = strdup(number) ?